# Some bootswatch themes don't import correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Is it me or do some of the bootswatch themes don't import when you import them.

I've been using slate and cyborg for all my practice applications, and now that I'm building a real one I wanted to use a less dark theme so I went with lux and sketchy, and neither of them worked I got this error "Sass::SyntaxError at /
File to import not found or unreadable: bootswatch/lux/variables."

So far through trouble shooting I can tell you that i can switch between slate and cyborg and it works just fine. but if I switch out the theme name for lux or sketchy its unable to load the paths?

this is how I'm importing them in my application.scss

```
@import "bootswatch/lux/variables";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootswatch/lux/bootswatch";
```

and my gem filelooks like this: 
    gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.3'

```
gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.6'

gem 'bootswatch-rails'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out that some bootswatch themes don't work as gems and the only way to get those themes is by downloading and physically putting them into your css